# PHP date format - date if date or nothing if null

Tags: php

I have this function to format a date from the database into a human-friendly format, but the date is an optional field and can be null.  Is there an elegant way for date be formatted if it exists or be  ' ' if it is null?

```
public function start_date_formatted()
{
    return date("M j, 'y", strtotime($this->start_date));
}
```

Comment: `isset()`, or maybe `empty()` check befor the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public function start_date_formatted()
{
    if( !is_null($this->start_date) ) {
      return date("M j, 'y", strtotime($this->start_date));
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
public function start_date_formatted()
    {
        if ($this->start_date)) {
            return date("M j, 'y", strtotime($this->start_date));
        } else {
            return 0; // or whatever you want to return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper to validate date:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can uset isset, it will check if the date is set or not

```
public function start_date_formatted()
{
    if ( isset($this->start_date) && !( is_null($this->start_date) ) ) { // Check if the properties is set and not null (maybe is_null is overkill)
        return date("M j, 'y", strtotime($this->start_date));
    } else {
       return '';
    }
}
```